# yarn test - Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

created a react project using create-react-app however when  I go to run `yarn test` to see if the initial tests pass I get

```
/home/afenwick/Development/road-to-react-learning/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:22
throw err;
^
TypeError: Network request failed`
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If I set up a brand new app it works totally fine, have not made any changes to App.test.js, just trying to run the default test. `yarn start` works fine, spins up my app in the browser.
Have tried deleting `node_modules`
Also tried `npm install` instead and `npm run tests` but that doesnt install my dependencies and then also errors the tests.
OS: Antergos Linux
Github repo: https://github.com/Fenwick17/road-to-react-learning
Stepped through my commits to locate the issue, and appears to be caused in https://github.com/Fenwick17/road-to-react-learning/commit/4b6069181a39861e531b550ebb8689695db042bb so I will work through the changes to rectify.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure that you made no changes to the project before calling `yarn test`?

Comment: I have made changes to my project, but not the tests itself. The current test is default `renders without crashing`. Which does start correctly. Github repo: https://github.com/Fenwick17/road-to-react-learning

Comment: Please narrow it down to a [MCVE]. Links to projects or source files in a question are frowned upon.

Comment: I would also advise you to create an app from scratch and immediately call `yarn test`, so as to understand whether your changes are affecting them.

Comment: Sorry, was not aware of that. I have narrowed it down by stepping back through my commits. Tests ran fine until https://github.com/Fenwick17/road-to-react-learning/commit/4b6069181a39861e531b550ebb8689695db042bb That appears to be the commit that caused the failure.

Comment: Again, you are expected to update your question with the necessary explanations and contents to reproduce the issue. At this point, it doesn't sound that much like an issue with yarn or jest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also ran into this problem when following the book entitled "The Road to Learn React" and I think that the one causing this error is the part where `fetch` is called. The book forgot to include an import for fetch which is this one:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
```

Then, it solves my problem like a charm. Hope this help.

Comment: Where'd you place that import statement? Placing it in my own tests does not work.